# How to extract information with regex_search on Ansible

Tags: regex, ansible

I want to test the presence of the new version before upgrading my Postgres on Debian.

I get the information from this task.

```yaml
- name: check version
  command: apt-cache policy postgresql-{{postgresql_version}}
  register: __postgres_update

- name: var version 
  ansible.builtin.debug: 
  var: __postgres_update.stdout_lines[1:2]
```

I want to keep only the result numbers

```yaml
ok: [test-xxx] => {
    "__postgres_update.stdout_lines[1:2]": [
        "  Candidat : **15.5**-1.pgdg120+1"
      ]
    }
```

my task

```yaml
- name: version  
  debug:
    msg: "{{ __postgres_update.stdout_lines[1:2] | regex_search('\b(\d[\d.]*)') }}"
```

I have a error but the quotes are correct
The offending line appears to be:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ __postgres_update.stdout_lines[1:2] | regex_search('\b(\d[\d.]*)') }}"
```

Thank you.

I tested my search in https://regex101.com/r/9YXAkc/3 and It work. I don't understand the problem can you help me!

Comment: Try `regex_search('\\b(\d+(?:\\.\\d+)+)')`

Comment: I think your regex does [not work even online](https://regex101.com/r/9YXAkc/20).

Comment: Use named regex groups `(?<name>[0-9A-Za-z]+)`

Comment: If you told Ansible which version of package to install, it would do these checks anyway and upgrade if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

***I want to test the presence of the a version before upgrading, I like to get the information from this task before.***

Also in such case it is recommended to use the specific Ansible Modules for. This is shown in the following minimal example based on Red Hat and `yum` for `golang` package

```sh
yum list installed golang
Installed Packages
golang.x86_64    1.19.13-1.el7    @epel-7
```

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Gather Package Updates
    yum:
      list: updates
      update_cache: true
    register: __result

  - name: Show Update
    debug:
      msg: "{{ (__result.results | selectattr('name', 'search', 'golang') | list | first) }}"

  - name: Show Version
    debug:
      msg: "{{ (__result.results | selectattr('name', 'search', 'golang') | list | first).version }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show Update] *************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    arch: x86_64
    envra: 0:golang-bin-1.20.10-3.el7.x86_64
    epoch: '0'
    name: golang-bin
    release: 3.el7
    repo: epel-7
    version: 1.20.10
    yumstate: available

TASK [Show Version] ************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 1.20.10
```

but it should become easily adopted and adjusted according your infrastructure.